# Angular: uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using Angular template driven forms and i get this error:

compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

my html:

`<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <input type="text" name="gender" #gender="ngModel">
  </form>`

app.module:

```
import { HeaderModule } from 'src/app/components/header/header.module';
import { DemographicInfoComponent } from './pages/demographic-info/demographic-info.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { EditMyProfileComponent } from "./pages/edit-my-profile/edit-my-profile.component";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { PurchaseComponent } from "./pages/purchase/purchase.component";
import { CharacterTypeInfoComponent } from "./pages/character-type-info/character-type-info.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EditMyProfileComponent,
    PurchaseComponent,
    CharacterTypeInfoComponent,
    DemographicInfoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HeaderModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    //StoreModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `[(ngModel)]` in your `<input>` tag

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <input type="text" name="gender" #gender="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="gender" >
  </form>
```

in your `component.ts` declare the `gender` variable

```
class YourComponent {
  gender: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when there is an error in the template itself, i see you have not closed the **`<input>`**

```
 <input type="text" name="gender" #gender="ngModel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add ngModel:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <input type="text" name="gender" ->ngModel<- #gender="ngModel">
</form>
```